# Add field which flags first row after Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Select statement that looks a bit like this (shortened here as its just selecting fields from an existing table and nothing overly complicated)

```
 SELECT  
    CASE 
        WHEN dbo.Account_Inventory.NUMBER IS NULL THEN 'C' + CAST(CAST(dbo.Account_Inventory.CUST_ID AS bigint) AS nvarchar) 
        WHEN dbo.Account_Inventory.CUST_ID IS NULL THEN 'A' + CAST(CAST(dbo.Account_Inventory.ACCT_NUM AS bigint) AS nvarchar) 
        ELSE 'M' + CAST(CAST(dbo.Account_Inventory.NUMBER AS bigint) AS varchar) 
    END AS ID,
    CASE... 
    
...FROM     
    dbo.Account_Inventory LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dorm ON dbo.Account_Inventory.ACCT_NUM = dbo.Dorm.ACCT_NUM
WHERE  
    (dbo.Account_Inventory.ACCT_CLOSE_DT IS NULL) AND 
    (CASE 
        WHEN dbo.Account_Inventory.XYZ = 'Yes' AND dbo.Account_Inventory.BUS_LINE_CDE IN ('BB', 'BBM', 'ABC', 'ABCD') THEN 'ABC' 
        WHEN dbo.Account_Inventory.XYZ = 'YES' THEN 'EFG' 
        ELSE dbo.Account_Inventory.GLOBAL_BUSINESS 
    END IN ('BIG', 'SMAL','ABC')) 
ORDER BY 
    Order By
         ID, dbo.Account_Inventory.INT_DAILY_RATE DESC
```

After this, I want to add a field which will flag the first record (ID field) and mark it as "Unique" and the other records as "na".

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would be great if you could post the full query and sample data if possible.

Comment: Updating my original post with full code.  Note that the select statement is rather long so i've shortened it.  But should be enough to illustrate the point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use case statement.

```
case when row_number() over (order by ID, Rate desc) =1 then 'Unique' else 'na'
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's just been a long day but I can't figure out how to add this

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I finally made it work

```
WITH "temp_results" AS (SELECT  

CASE 
        WHEN dbo.Account_Inventory.NUMBER IS NULL THEN 'C' + CAST(CAST(dbo.Account_Inventory.CUST_ID AS bigint) AS nvarchar) 
        WHEN dbo.Account_Inventory.CUST_ID IS NULL THEN 'A' + CAST(CAST(dbo.Account_Inventory.ACCT_NUM AS bigint) AS nvarchar) 
        ELSE 'M' + CAST(CAST(dbo.Account_Inventory.NUMBER AS bigint) AS varchar) 
    END AS ID,
    CASE... 

*MORE CASE STATEMENTS*
    
...FROM     
    dbo.Account_Inventory LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dorm ON dbo.Account_Inventory.ACCT_NUM = dbo.Dorm.ACCT_NUM
WHERE  
    (dbo.Account_Inventory.ACCT_CLOSE_DT IS NULL) AND 
    (CASE 
        WHEN dbo.Account_Inventory.XYZ = 'Yes' AND dbo.Account_Inventory.BUS_LINE_CDE IN ('BB', 'BBM', 'ABC', 'ABCD') THEN 'ABC' 
        WHEN dbo.Account_Inventory.XYZ = 'YES' THEN 'EFG' 
        ELSE dbo.Account_Inventory.GLOBAL_BUSINESS 
    END IN ('BIG', 'SMAL','ABC')) 
ORDER BY
         ID, dbo.Account_Inventory.INT_DAILY_RATE DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS)

SELECT "Rel ID", "Rel_Name"...

*LIST ALL FIELDS*

...(CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(PARTITION BY "Rel_ID" ORDER BY Rel_ID, INT_DAILY_RATE desc)=1 THEN 'Unique' ELSE 'na' END) AS "Unique_Rel_Flag" FROM "temp_results"
```

What I was stuck on the longest is ending the first Order By statement with "OFFSET 0 ROWS".  It will not work without that.

```
ORDER BY
         ID, dbo.Account_Inventory.INT_DAILY_RATE DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS)
```

Hope that helps someone else out down the line!